# Proof of bijection for $\Phi(p)=(p'', p'(0), p(0) )$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, polynomials, inverse-function

Let $\Phi: \mathbb{P} _3 \to \mathbb{P} _1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be given by the assignment rule $\Phi(p)=(p'', p'(0), p(0))$.

I am asked:

Prove that $\Phi$ is a bijection.

Here's my attempt:

Let $p_1,p_2$ take on the general form $p_1=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$ for some arbitrary $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}$, and $p_2=ex^3+fx^2+gx+h$ for some arbitrary $e,f,g,h\in \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f(p_1)=f(p_2)$. Therefore $p_1''=p_2''$, so by taking second derivatives, $6ax+2b=6ex+2f\implies a=e$ and $b=f$. Also, $p_1'(0)=p_2'(0)$, so $c=g$. Finally, $p_1(0)=p_2(0)$, so $d=h$. Since all of the coefficients of $p_1$ and $p_2$ are respectively equal, we can say that $p_1=p_2$, and thus $f(p_1)=f(p_2)\implies p_1=p_2$. Since these values for $p_1$ and $p_2$ were arbitrary, the function $\Phi$ is injective.

Let $(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be generic. Choose $p=\frac{1}{6}ax^3+\frac{1}{2}bx^2+cx+d$. Then $$\Phi(p)=(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(\frac{1}{6}ax^3+\frac{1}{2}bx^2+cx+d), \frac{1}{2}a\cdot0^2+b\cdot0+c, \frac{1}{6}a\cdot0^3+\frac{1}{2}b\cdot0^2+c\cdot0+d) = (ax+b,c,d)$$

Since $(ax+b,c,d)$ was generic, we can verify the statement $\forall(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},\exists p\in \mathbb{P}_3,\Phi(p)=(p'',p'(0),p(0))$. Therefore, the function $\Phi$ is surjective.

Since $\Phi$ is both injective and surjective, it must be bijective. $\blacksquare$

Did I miss anything? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *reasoning* is perfectly fine and well done. There is just a couple of not serious remarks we can make on your *wording*.

> "Let $(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be *generic*."
>
> "Since $(ax+b,c,d)$ was *generic*, we can verify the statement..."

We usually use the word *arbitrary*, which has the more accurate meaning of "choosen at your will" or "any element", instead of *generic*, that have a more "generic"(vague, wide) meaning of "not specified" or "undetermined". Also the arbitrariness is implicit in a sentence starting with "Let...". So you may reword to

> "Let $(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$."
>
> "Since $(ax+b,c,d)$ is arbitrary, we can verify the statement..."

(As a side note I would write "it follows that" instead of "we can verify the statement".)

Now about

> $$\forall(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},\exists p\in \mathbb{P}_3,\Phi(p)=(p'',p'(0),p(0))$$

I think you meant to write

> $$\forall(ax+b,c,d)\in \mathbb{P}_1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R},\exists p\in \mathbb{P}_3,\Phi(p)=(ax+b,c,d)$$

because this is what you shown and $\Phi(p)=(p'', p'(0), p(0))$ holds for any $p$, since it is the very definition of $\Phi$.

And finnaly

> Since $\Phi$ is both injective and surjective, it must be bijective.

It is not that it *must* be bijective. It is that it is bijective by *definition*.

I don't know if you are familiar with linear algebra but here is an alternative proof using linear algebra so you can study the text.

***Proof.*** Since $\mathbb{P} _3$ and $\mathbb{P} _1 \times \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ with the usual operations of sum and scalar multiplication are both $4$-dimensional vector spaces it is enough to show that $\Phi$ is linear and $\Phi(p) = \vec{0} \implies p = 0$ because for a linear transformation between vector spaces of same dimensions it holds that
$$\Phi \text{ bijective} \iff \Phi \text{ injective} \iff \Phi^{-1}(\{0\}) = \{0\} \iff \left(\Phi(p) = \vec{0} \implies p = 0\right)$$

Thus, let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $p,q \in \mathbb{P}_3$. So
$$\begin{align}
\Phi(\lambda p + q) &= ((\lambda p + q)'', (\lambda p + q)'(0), (\lambda p + q)(0))\\
&= (\lambda p'' + q'', \lambda p'(0) + q'(0), \lambda p(0) + q(0))\\
&= (\lambda p'', \lambda p'(0), \lambda p(0)) + (q'', q'(0), q(0))\\
&= \lambda(p'', p'(0), p(0)) + (q'', q'(0), q(0))\\
&= \lambda \Phi(p) + \Phi(q)
\end{align}$$

Therefore $\Phi$ is linear. Now suppose that $\Phi(p) = \vec{0}$. Then $p'' = 0$, $p'(0) = 0$ and $p(0) = 0$, whence $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ it follows that
$$ p'(x) = p'(0) + \int_0^x p''(x)\ dx = 0 $$
and
$$ p(x) = p(0) + \int_0^x p'(x)\ dx = 0 $$

Hence $p = 0$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Notice that the fact that $p$ is a polynomial is not used anywhere in this proof. This means that the bijectivity of $\Phi$ holds for more general spaces. For example,the space of the two times differentiable functions between $\mathbb{R}$ and itself: $\mathscr{D}^2(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ rather than $\mathbb{P}_3$ and the space of the continuous functions $C(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ rather than $\mathbb{P}_1$. (Actually it is possible to consider even more general spaces.)